# Clarification on the complexity of Interior Point Method for general convex problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, computational-complexity, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I am trying to find the computational complexity of interior point method for a general convex problem and stumbled upon the following complexity in Section 1.3.1 of Convex Optimization by Stephen Boyd:
\begin{align}
\max\{n^3,n^2m,F\}
\end{align}
$n$ is the number of optimization variables and $m$ is the number of constraints. $F$ is the cost of evaluating the first and second derivatives of the objective function and constraints. However, I am not sure how this is obtained. Could anyone help me understand how this complexity is derived (or refer me to a paper/book explaining this)?

Also, if my objective function needs $T$ operations to be evaluated. How does the above formula change? Thanks!